# ./flash-all.sh: line 16: fastboot: command not found

Tags: android-sdk

I'm trying to "Get Started" with [Setting Up the Preview SDK | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html) to Install the L Preview System Image [Android L Developer Preview | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/preview/index.html) on my Nexus 7 (Wifi) "razor".

I'm getting following error:

```
mbp:razor-lpv79 alexus$ ./flash-all.sh 
./flash-all.sh: line 17: fastboot: command not found
./flash-all.sh: line 18: fastboot: command not found
^C
mbp:razor-lpv79 alexus$
```

here is my `fastboot`, it's in `/Applications/Android Developer Tools/sdk/platform-tools/` folder:

```
mbp:razor-lpv79 alexus$ ls /Applications/Android\ Developer\ Tools/sdk/platform-tools/fastboot 
/Applications/Android Developer Tools/sdk/platform-tools/fastboot
mbp:razor-lpv79 alexus$
```

What can I do? I do *NOT* wish to modify `flash-all.sh` script (if possible).

Comment: Assuming you are using Mac/Linux OS, try using sudo ./ before all fastboot command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't an Android problem at all. You can simply run the commands from flash-all.sh by hand, changing each one to name `fastboot` by its full path, or you can set the `$PATH` in your shell.

```
PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Android Developer Tools/sdk/platform-tools/"
./flash-all.sh
```

You should also check that the `fastboot` executable is executable. This probably won't be the case if you've extracted the files onto a non-ext partition. The following output is a correct example: note the `x` in the fourth column, and that the files are owned by the user I'm running as.

```
z1@foyle platform-tools% ls -l
total 3292
-rwxr-xr-x 1 z1 z1 1355536 1105 27 Jun 14 adb
drwxr-xr-x 2 z1 z1    4096 1105 27 Jun 14 api
-rwxr-xr-x 1 z1 z1   47828 1105 27 Jun 14 dmtracedump
-rwxr-xr-x 1 z1 z1  225253 1105 27 Jun 14 etc1tool
-rwxr-xr-x 1 z1 z1  201380 1105 27 Jun 14 fastboot
-rwxr-xr-x 1 z1 z1   10071 1105 27 Jun 14 hprof-conv
-rw-r--r-- 1 z1 z1  720629 1105 27 Jun 14 NOTICE.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 z1 z1   16520 1105 27 Jun 14 source.properties
-rwxr-xr-x 1 z1 z1  771959 1105 27 Jun 14 sqlite3
drwxr-xr-x 2 z1 z1    4096 1105 27 Jun 14 systrace
```

Comment: I ran `export PATH=$PATH$:'/Applications/Android\ Developer\ Tools/sdk/platform-tools/'` (echo `$PATH` returns updated `$PATH`), yet still getting `-bash: fastboot: command not found`.

Comment: There's an extra `$` sign in your command.

Answer (score 1):

I was running today into a similar issue as the one that you are pointing out. I downloaded my .img file from https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images and tried to run:

```
flash-all.sh
```

But that was returning:

```
./flash-all.sh: line 17: fastboot: command not found
./flash-all.sh: line 18: fastboot: command not found
```

My solution (in my Mac) was to download the file RootNexus5.zip from http://downloadandroidfiles.org/download-rootnexus5-zip-2/ decompress the downloaded file and copy *fastboot-mac* into the same folder as *flash-all.sh*.

Now open flash-all.sh in your favourite editor (Sublime in my case) and change all the ocurrences of *fastboot* for *./fastboot-mac*. Then try to run the file again. If you are not using a Mac simply use *fastboot-linux*.

Note: Linux users in my case was debian 9.8 stretch.

Make sure adb and fastboot are installed.

```
sudo apt-get install adb 
sudo apt-get install fastboot
```

fixed my error straight away. I already had adb but not fastboot.

Comment: I also mention that i do _NOT_ wish to edit `flash-all.sh`, as I could easily change path to it and call it a day!

Comment: The *(if possible)* at the end tricked me then ;-)